# How to derive the molar fundamental relation

Tags: thermodynamics

We have the fundamental relation: 
$$dS = \frac{1}{T}dU+\frac{P}{T}dV-\frac{\mu}{T}dN$$
how do we get now the following:
$$ds = \frac{1}{T}du+\frac{P}{T}dv$$ where $s = \frac{S}{N}, u = \frac{U}{N}, v = \frac{V}{N}$.
I tried substitution but it got me nowhere..

Comment: Did you use the product rule for differentiation?

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes

Comment: Let's see what that gave you.

Comment: $Nds+sdN = \frac{1}{T}(Ndu+udN)+\frac{P}{T}(Ndv+vdN)-\frac{\mu}{T}dN$

Comment: but why should $\frac{s}{N}dN+\frac{u}{NT}dN+\frac{Pv}{NT}dN-\frac{\mu}{TN}dN$ be zero

Comment: You're missing a factor of v in the term involving P.  Factor out the dN/N.  What does that give you?  What is the definition of $\mu$?

Comment: we did define it as $\mu = \frac{\partial U}{\partial N}$ but if we use the Gibbs-Duhem-relation it equals zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  $$ds=\frac{du}{T}+\frac{P}{T}dv+\left(\frac{u}{T}-s+\frac{Pv}{T}-\frac{\mu}{T}\right)\frac{dN}{N}$$
But, $$\mu=u+Pv-Ts$$
That is, $\mu$ is the Gibbs free energy per mole.  So the term in parenthesis drops out.